# Visual Studio 2022. Feature 'Edit and Continue' is currently unavailable due to an internal error. Read out of bounds

Tags: .net, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2022, postsharp

Suddenly I have started to get aforementioned issue during debugging unit tests.
Here is a situation:

1. Open project and open Tests Explorer.
2. Select any test and try to debug it.
3. Got message from title below the tool bar and break point in test would not be honored.

Things I tried with no avail:

1. Update VS version. Has been:17.3.3 Now:17.3.6
2. Repair VS.

Here is stack trace:

StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Read out of bounds.
at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__1431.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditAndContinue.RemoteEditAndContinueServiceProxy.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceConnection1.d__201.MoveNext() RPC server exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Read out of bounds.       at System.Reflection.Throw.OutOfBounds()       at System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335.CustomDebugInformationTableReader..ctor(Int32 numberOfRows, Boolean declaredSorted, Int32 hasCustomDebugInformationRefSize, Int32 guidHeapRefSize, Int32 blobHeapRefSize, MemoryBlock containingBlock, Int32 containingBlockOffset)       at System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.InitializeTableReaders(MemoryBlock metadataTablesMemoryBlock, HeapSizes heapSizes, Int32[] rowCounts, Int32[] externalRowCountsOpt)       at System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader..ctor(Byte* metadata, Int32 length, MetadataReaderOptions options, MetadataStringDecoder utf8Decoder, Object memoryOwner)       at System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReaderProvider.GetMetadataReader(MetadataReaderOptions options, MetadataStringDecoder utf8Decoder)       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Debugging.DebugInformationReaderProvider.Portable.CreateEditAndContinueMethodDebugInfoReader()       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditAndContinue.CommittedSolution.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditAndContinue.CommittedSolution.d__15.MoveNext()    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditAndContinue.EditAndContinueWorkspaceService.d__10.MoveNext()    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditAndContinue.RemoteEditAndContinueService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteWorkspace.<>c__DisplayClass10_01.<g__TryFastGetSolutionAndRunAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.RemoteWorkspace.d__101.MoveNext()    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)       at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceBase.d__111.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceBase.d__14`1.MoveNext()

Comment: The BadImageFormatException seems very significant, something is wrong with the debugging info, nobody else seems to have this problem.  Could be file corruption or anti-malware.  If it is a bug then switching Project > Properties > Build tab > Advanced > Debugging Information between Full or Portable could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crisis been averted. After following actions situation went back 2 normal:

1. Uninstalled Postsharp nuget from Tests project
2. Removed from test project file following section:

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" Version="3.11.0">
       <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
       <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles;analyzers;buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
   </PackageReference>
   ```

And after those actions no errors been produced and break points in tests been hit as expected. Weird.